# Find the matched rows based on redeem value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am implementing the cashback functionality with expiry feature. I am trying to redeem the partial amount based on early expiry date. I've already ordered the rows based on expiry date with the following mysql command.

```
SELECT * FROM `cashback` WHERE `user_id` = 1 and `used`= 'NO' AND IF(CONCAT(`point_expiry`) !='0000-00-00 00:00:00', `point_expiry` >= NOW(), NOW()) ORDER BY (case when CONCAT(`point_expiry`) = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then 9999
    else 1
    end) ASC, `point_expiry` ASC
```

And the output for the following will be

| id | amount | point_expiry | used | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 30 | 2023-02-24 00:00:00 | NO | 1 |
| 1 | 20 | 2023-02-25 00:00:00 | NO | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | NO | 1 |

Now i want to redeem the value based on the above query result

Let say i want to redeem `35$` for the above result and the expected result will be

| id | amount | point_expiry | used | used_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 30 | 2023-02-24 00:00:00 | NO | 30 |
| 1 | 20 | 2023-02-25 00:00:00 | NO | 5 |

Here `used_amount` column represent the specific redeem value($35) redeemed based on `amount` column

Much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY ...)` to calculate a running total and compares it to the balance -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        `id`,
        `amount`,
        `point_expiry`,
        `used`,
        `amount` - GREATEST(SUM(`amount`) OVER (ORDER BY IF(`point_expiry` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 0) ASC, `point_expiry` ASC, id ASC) - /* Here is your amount --> */ 35, 0) AS `used_amount`
    FROM `cashback`
    WHERE (`point_expiry` >= NOW() OR `point_expiry` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    AND `used` = 'NO'
    AND `user_id` = 1
) t
WHERE `used_amount` > 0;
```